# solving system of differential equation used in HIV modeling by matlab

Tags: matlab

I am really fearing with my project thesis and I need a desperate help..I am working on a HIV modeling and there are several's of non linear differential equations. I need them to be solved but I can't figure it out to solve it by matlab, the equations are The equations are here[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you define some more of the terms, particularly if they are functions?

Comment: Couldn't find the attachment.  Where is it?  Good, timely, relevant question.  +1.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Sorry there was no attachment the equation are as the above.please see the parameters value given below the equations..